# Syntax Error in Formula Field

Tags: apex, formula-field, salesforcedx

Error:

Incorrect parameter type for function 'IF()'. Expected Boolean, received Text

Code:

```
( VALUE(TEXT(Core_Competencies__c)) + VALUE(TEXT(Experience__c)) + VALUE(TEXT(Leadership_Skills__c)) + IF( Recommend_for_Hire__c , 5, 0) ) / 4
```

Comment: What is the field type for `Recommend_for_Hire__c`? Text? If so, what were you expecting the formula to evaluate? What value would equal true?

Comment: Field Type:Text Area(Long).

Comment: So what do you expect to happen when you evaluate `IF(My_Text_Area_Field__c, <value_if_true>, <value_if_false>)`? It is difficult to help you get to where you are trying to go without a little more detail on what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Format for if is `If(logical_test,value_if_true,value_if_false)`
`logical_test` must resolve to Boolean, either you can put Boolean field here or any expression which resolves to Boolean result like `Field1 == Field2`, `Field1 != Field2` etc, `value_if_true` and `value_if_false` can be of any type that you might want as output.

According to Salesforce documentation:

> IF(logical_test, value_if_true, value_if_false) and replace
>   logical_test with the expression you want evaluated; replace
>   value_if_true with the value you want returned if the expression is
>   true; replace value_if_false with the value you want returned if the
>   expression is false.

Here your field `Recommend_for_Hire__c` is text and not supported directly into if condition, if you have any particular requirement you can change it to Boolean expression.

[Reference](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_functions_i_z.htm&type=5)